# How to get the return value of setState(prev => (prev)) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a custom hook which wraps `setState` function so I can do something with the values as they are passed into the setter.

In this case, `setState` either takes a `string` value or a callback with the `prev` value of the state:

```js
setState((prev) => (prev + ' world')); // hello world
```

```js
const useHook = () => {
   const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState('hello');
   
   const setWrapper = (value: string | (prev: string) => string) => {
      // how can I get the result of (prev) => string here
      // aka 'hello world' value.
   }

   return [stateValue, setWrapper]
}
```

How can I get the return value passed to `setWrapped` if a callback with `prev` was used?

Comment: you can declare a variable, assign the new value to variable and add that variable in your returned list of hook.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call `setStateValue` in the wrapper function where you have access to the parameters as expected.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const useHook = () => {
   const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState('hello');
   
   const setWrapper = (newValue: string) => {
      return setStateValue(old => {
          console.log('Got old value: ', old);
          console.log('Returning new: ', old + newValue);
          return old + newValue;
      });
   }

   return [stateValue, setWrapper]
}


const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useHook('hello');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setValue(' world');
    }, [ ]);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <em>{value}</em>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: How would this work if I were to invert a boolean value instead of a string? Something like this `setValue((prev) => !prev)`. Should I just do `setValue(!value)` then?

Comment: In my example `return !old` would do that right?

Comment: Yes, but that would make it behave differently than a normal `setState` right? If possible I would like to keep the behaviour of `setValue` of the hook and `setState` from react the same. So that both `setValue((prev) => prev)` and `setValue('value')` are allowed.

Comment: Ahh so, you can't to that since the first option you pass an function and the second a string. You could check the type of the param to determine what to do with it, but that won't be much readable code.

Comment: Exactly, so when using an object value in this hook it won't work because I need access to the `prev` value if I want to update only one property of the object.

Comment: But then what is the point of the `setWrapper` if you can just use the hook? NOt sure what you're trying to achieve with that wrapper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251753/discussion-between-kipnoedels-and-0stone0).